# Query the records that the number of it is equal to the number of it in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

For example, `movieCopy(cp_id, movie_id), rental(cp_id, Date)` A movie has some copies and the copies have unique id. Rental table represent the record of renting movie copy(don't care return just rent once). I want to query which movie has been rent out all, that means the number of copy of a movie is equal to number of its number of possible cp_id in rental. MYSQL database

```
movie `cp_id   movie_id               rental cp_id   Date
       101        1                           101    2001
       102        1                           102    2001
       103        1                           103    2001
       104        2                           104    2002
       105        2                           106    2002
       106        3 `
```

I want to select movie_id, 1 and 3

Comment: Can you provider some data examples? What do you expect for output? What RDMS are you using? (Mysql,mssql,oracel) And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the columns you provided, this should work:

`Select movie_id
From movie
Where movie_id Not Exists
          (Select Movie_id
           From movie
           Where cp_id Not Exists (Select distinct cp_id
                                    From rental
                                    Where date between date1 and date2)`

date1 and date2 are just place holders in case you wanted to filter on them.

Comment: there are some mistakes, such as "where cp_id not exists". However, give me a idea to solve the problem